# different result from F5 and F9 when running the os.path.realpath

Tags: python, directory, os.path

I feel very confused about ***os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))***

Here is my confusion:

(1) If I open my script in spyder (***the first time***) and run the selected lines below (F9):

```
import os
import sys
dir_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

It returns:

```
dir_path = C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell
```

which is ***not*** the result I want.

(2) However, if I run my whole script (F5), I can get what I expect (***which is the current directory of my script***):

```
dir_path = C:\Users\abc\Desktop\py
```

(3) Additionally if I:

1. Run the whole script,
2. %reset variables,
3. Run the same selected lines as before,

I can still get ***the current directory of my script, as long as I don't exit spyder***:

```
dir_path = C:\Users\abc\Desktop\py
```

Gould anyone please explain something on this? It will be very appreciated. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your current complete pathname you can use

```
os.path.realpath(os.path.curdir)
```

As for the confusion, print the `sys.argv` to inspect it. Its content can hold different values, depending on how your script has been called. If I just enter into the python interpreter it holds a list with an empty string, but if I call `python myscript.py`, it will hold the script name followed by any arguments.